# How to save UITextField with Parse?

Tags: ios, input, uitextfield, save, parse-platform

I must be missing something but XCODE is throwing an error when I try the following:

```
PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"dance"];
[addValues setObject: self.dancePlace forKey:@"place_airport"];
[addValues setObject: self.danceGate forKey:@"gate_airport"];
[addValues setObject: self.danceStyle forKey:@"dance_style"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```

The error comes when I run the code and it tries to save the object I've set...and those values above in self.xxxxxxx are string values from an input field with the error it gives me is ->>>>

'PFObject values may not have class: UITextField'

I've tried to convert them to string values as NSString *valueDancePlace = self.dancePlace;

And then in the setObject statement ->

[addValues setObject: *valueDancePlace forKey:@"place_airport"];

which throws an obvious error of type mismatch....

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you getting the .text property of your UITextFields?

Comment: Looks like I was correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the **TEXT** of the UITextFields:

```
PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"dance"];
[addValues setObject: self.dancePlace.text forKey:@"place_airport"];
[addValues setObject: self.danceGate.text forKey:@"gate_airport"];
[addValues setObject: self.danceStyle.text forKey:@"dance_style"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```

Before you were getting the actual UITextFields.

Comment: @MagicMiles I think my way is more efficient.

Comment: @MagicMiles Why did you uncheck my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, as this is nowhere in the documentation for parse, this is the correct way to save your input values:

Assuming that in your .h file you have them listed like so ->

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dancePlace;
```

In your .m file you would do this ->

```
NSString *dancePlaceText = _dancePlace.text;

PFObject *addValues= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"dance"];
[addValues setObject: dancePlaceText forKey:@"place_airport"];
[addValues saveInBackground];
```